# Importing products. 3rd party or native?

Tags: magento2, importexport, import-products

I'm wondering if the magento 2 import is worth using. Back in M1 this process was just horrible and I remember only a couple thousand products taking over a half hour and then timing out partway through.

I switched to "unirgy urapidflow" and my imports only took seconds. However, now that I'm planning a move to m2, I'm wondering if the standard M2 import feature is actually worth using or if I should still consider a third party solution (if so which third party)... I was originally thinking of unirgy again but I think the company might be dead as they don't answer emails.

I want to be able to import products, tier prices, stock status. One nice thing about the urapidflow product was the ability to autocreate missing attribute values.

I appreciate all your advice and comments regarding your experience with m2 import/export or third party options.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The probably fastest option for Magento imports is Pacemaker: https://docs.met.tdintern.de/pacemaker/1.3/

There's a free community edition as well as commercial editions with more features. We've successfully used the solution in a few projects (disclaimer: my company is a Pacemaker solution partner).
For importing just a few products, the Magento import is probably good enough, for larger imports that should run fast, Pacemaker is my go-to solution.

Answer (score 0):

Magneto 2 comes with asynchronous bulk API. Which can be utilized to import bulk data. Any API endpoint can be converted to asynchronous bulk by appending " /async/bulk/" before any REST API endpoint. asynchronous bulk API uses a message queue to import data to DB.

I have tested asynchronous bulk API for product import and in one chunk I was able to push 50 products at a time. **The feature works smoothly when you have RabbitMQ configured as a message queue.**

DevDoc --> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/bulk-endpoints.html

Comment: So are you basically hinting that stock magento import via System>Data Transfer>Import>Products is no good/too slow. And you only recommend using custom import with API?